# Adding a hyperlink in word, with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink, word-2010

I'm currently trying to add a hyperlink to a web url in word through a VB program. I'm stumbling around to try and find the proper syntax and what I need to accomplish this, because I've been getting a lot of unhelpful VBA examples, which is not what I need at all.

My code looks like this:

```
sPara2 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
sPara2.Range.Text = attachmentRdr("attachmentName")
sPara2.Range.Hyperlinks.Add(attachmentRdr("attachmentPath"))
sPara2.Format.SpaceAfter = 24    '24 pt spacing after paragraph.
sPara2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
```

where `attachmentRdr` is a `sqlDatareader` reading strings of text (attachment name, and path) from a database. If I run this, I get an error for bad parameters (which gets' proced off of the `hyperlinks.add()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass range through as the first parameter to the Add function, followed by your URL:

```
Dim range As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range
range = Me.Application.Selection.Range
range.Hyperlinks.Add(range, "http://www.microsoft.com")
```