# VB scripting Add hyperlinks

Tags: vb.net

I want to add several hyperlinks in a word document using VBscript.

but I am able to add the hyperlinks at the same place everytime overwriting the previous one.

*Code Provided by Author*

```
For TRow = 2 To Target_LastRow 
    ObjWord.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add 
    Anchor:=SAnchr, _ Address:=getExcelObj.Worksheets(2).Cells(TRow, 4).Value, _
      TextToDisplay:="Link" & (TRow - 1)
```

Comment: This is what my program looks like.I am able to add hyperlinks in excel in different cell.But unable to add hyperlinks in doc one after another..

Comment: Please show some code that you have worked on so we can help.

Comment: For TRow = 2 To Target_LastRow
                
                
                ObjWord.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=SAnchr, _
                Address:=getExcelObj.Worksheets(2).Cells(TRow, 4).Value, _
                TextToDisplay:="Link" & (TRow - 1)  I am looping through a excel file to pick up the address and adding it to a word doc.but as the loop goes on the previous address is overridden by the latest one.How to change the anchor every time.

Comment: You're going to want to show the code up above, so its nice and formatted. Ill change this for you this time, it still feels like your missing quite a bit of code.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I could find by the code provided by you. I hope this is a start.

```
ObjWord.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=Ank, Address:=M, SubAddress:=SA, ScreenTip:=M, TextToDisplay:=M, Target:=M)
```

You can go a step simpler and just place it like so *Range would be "A1-B2"* Or something similar

```
range.Hyperlinks.Add(range, "http://www.microsoft.com")
```

I also would recomend you follow [This Link](http://janewdaisy.wordpress.com/2012/03/02/how-to-insert-hyperlink-in-word-document-with-cvb-net/)

Sources [1](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/100145-inserting-hyperlinks-in-a-word-document-with-vbnet/),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389464/adding-a-hyperlink-in-word-with-vb-net)

**Update**

To add to your overwriting, you must change the value that you chose to represent the range or area of insertion. *A wild hunch of mine tells me that it would be the `anchor` Variable*

Comment: Instead I add a paragraph on each iteration..and that solved the problem..(y)